How to Find the Package Name Generated by Amazon AppStore for an App with AdMob Ads?
I made an app with AdMob ads and uploaded it to the Amazon AppStore. Everything went well until now. The problem is that I need to fill out the App Store details, and it asks for the store it's in and the package name. However, it says that the name is not the same as the package name, and that Amazon generates a different package name. Where can I find it?
